# Laravel joining two models to User model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have the following tables:

Users
Games
Characters

A user will have one active game at a time, and from that game, will have one active character.

I want to perform the following joi on my authentication table:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN games ON games.ID = users.active_gameid
LEFT OUTER JOIN characters ON characters.ID = games.active_charid
```

Try to ignore the SELECT * part.

I'd like to perform these joins on my Auth table as soon as the page loads, so I have been using my User model to do the following:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function game() {
        return $this->hasOne('game', 'ID', 'active_gameid');
    }

}

class game extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "games";

    public function character() {
        return $this->hasOne('character', 'ID', 'active_charid');
    }

}

class character extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = "characters";

}
```

The above doesn't work as outputting the following just returns a NULL value:

```
var_dump(Auth::user()->game->character);
```

I have tried to do the obvious checks such as making sure the data is in the table and such and  that all seems fine.

Does anyone have any help on where I'm going wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try var_dumping `Auth::user()` and `Auth::user()->game` by themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Your relations are wrong:

```
// User model
public function game()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Game', 'active_gameid', 'ID');
}

// Game model
public function character()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Character', 'active_charid', 'ID');
}
```

and obviously it won't call your query, but 2 separate queries:

```
Auth::user()
  ->game // SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID = ?
  ->character; // SELECT * FROM characters WHERE ID = ?
```

Comment: It looks like that the `User` contains the `game` id (users.active_gameid), and the `game` contains the `character` id (games.active_charid), so shouldn't it be that the user belongs to the game and the game belongs to the character?

Comment: @patricus Sure it is! I didn't read the whole thing carefully.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. My game Model:

`class Game extends Eloquent {
 protected $table = "games";

 public function character() {
  return $this->belongsTo('characters', 'active_charid', 'ID');
 }
}

class characters extends Eloquent {
}`

Comment: explain `doesn't work` and edit your question with tables you have.

Comment: Added, apologies for the formatting... SO newbie here :(

    `class Game extends Eloquent { protected $table = "games"; public function character() { return $this->belongsTo('characters', 'active_charid', 'ID'); } } class characters extends Eloquent { }`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I think you need to switch the keys, as well. `hasOne(relation, foreign_key, local_key)`, but `belongsTo(relation, local_key, parent_key)`.

Comment: @patricus Well, you're right and wrong. `local_key` in your example is `foreign_key`, and `belongsTo` just like `hasOne/Many` takes foreign_key as 2nd param always.

Comment: @Patchesoft OK, but you're not telling us what doesn't work for you.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thank you for your help! I have solved it now- for some reason one of my Models had an underscore in the name and it didn't like that. The belongsTo was correct :) Thanks!

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk You're right. I was looking at the docs, which is where that terminology came from. I now see how they were trying to explain it. Looking at the actual code made it a bit clearer.